# How to find in specific date interval

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have problem in Mongodb to find wanted documents and fragment of list field. So I have following document:

```
{
  "_id": "5ed38e5d2a6e74567c7a579c",
  "id": "AAA",
  "events": [
{
  "dayTypeId": "5e71e1918ee9a326ebdf1611",
  "startDate": {
    "$date": "2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "endDate": {
    "$date": "2020-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "stared": false,
  "userId": "XXX",
  "mixing": "wjk0ra1v7m88p0x5aaxwndkmwmlxx4pn92hzjlgpl34u8ojx855m8e8spp1v7l57omtoc4qxbv0g22nybqubd3hq5skuff8ezbzdum2a92itwco64tbi5y2p5mboznxiuwynv0rb8eqk9d80ib65cve6ab9p1d1divee3wbywc2st1lkjruqvgu42zgx8mjtsnb8gyeqtxycl4ujpllgxpshdu8o97iiw347bjqv4mrv6jgwq4r21zp5rm4dw6a1"
},
{
  "dayTypeId": "5e71e1918ee9a326ebdf1611",
  "startDate": {
    "$date": "2020-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "endDate": {
    "$date": "2020-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "stared": false,
  "userId": "XXX",
  "mixing": "wjk0ra1v7m88p0x5aaxwndkmwmlxx4pn92hzjlgpl34u8ojx855m8e8spp1v7l57omtoc4qxbv0g22nybqubd3hq5skuff8ezbzdum2a92itwco64tbi5y2p5mboznxiuwynv0rb8eqk9d80ib65cve6ab9p1d1divee3wbywc2st1lkjruqvgu42zgx8mjtsnb8gyeqtxycl4ujpllgxpshdu8o97iiw347bjqv4mrv6jgwq4r21zp5rm4dw6a1"
},
{
  "dayTypeId": "5e71d8628ee9a326e7df160d",
  "startDate": {
    "$date": "2020-06-05T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "endDate": {
    "$date": "2020-06-09T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "stared": false,
  "userId": "XXX",
  "mixing": "wjk0ra1v7m88p0x5aaxwndkmwmlxx4pn92hzjlgpl34u8ojx855m8e8spp1v7l57omtoc4qxbv0g22nybqubd3hq5skuff8ezbzdum2a92itwco64tbi5y2p5mboznxiuwynv0rb8eqk9d80ib65cve6ab9p1d1divee3wbywc2st1lkjruqvgu42zgx8mjtsnb8gyeqtxycl4ujpllgxpshdu8o97iiw347bjqv4mrv6jgwq4r21zp5rm4dw6a1"
    },
{
  "dayTypeId": "5e71d8628ee9a326e7df160d",
  "startDate": {
    "$date": "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "endDate": {
    "$date": "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "stared": false,
  "userId": "XXXX",
  "mixing": "wjk0ra1v7m88p0x5aaxwndkmwmlxx4pn92hzjlgpl34u8ojx855m8e8spp1v7l57omtoc4qxbv0g22nybqubd3hq5skuff8ezbzdum2a92itwco64tbi5y2p5mboznxiuwynv0rb8eqk9d80ib65cve6ab9p1d1divee3wbywc2st1lkjruqvgu42zgx8mjtsnb8gyeqtxycl4ujpllgxpshdu8o97iiw347bjqv4mrv6jgwq4r21zp5rm4dw6a1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get fragment of "events" list where either the `startDate` or the `endDate` is in the range of `02.06.2020-11.06.2020`.

For example out of my sample data I want all but the last element to be returned.

Comment: Which field is the target for your range interval: `startDate` or `endDate`?  Or both
?

Comment: Both of them. startDate: 02.06.2020, endDate: 11.06.2020. I used $gte and $lte but i didn't get correct result.

Comment: So...   your range interval must cover the start AND end, meaning interval_start is gte `startDate` and interval_end is lte `endDate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter out any events that do not match your conditions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    "events.startDate": {$gte: new Date("2020-06-02"), $lte: new Date("2020-06-11")}
                },
                {
                    "events.endDate": {$gte: new Date("2020-06-02"), $lte: new Date("2020-06-11")}
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
           events: {
               $filter: {
                   input: "$events",
                   as: "event",
                   cond: {
                       $or: [
                           {
                               $and: [
                                   {$gte: ["$$event.startDate", new Date("2020-06-02")]},
                                   {$lte: ["$$event.startDate", new Date("2020-06-11")]},
                               ]
                           },
                           {
                               $and: [
                                   {$gte: ["$$event.endDate", new Date("2020-06-02")]},
                                   {$lte: ["$$event.endDate", new Date("2020-06-11")]},
                               ]
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               }
           } 
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: My friend,this code is not working because of "startDate" and "endDate" located in "events" list. Please take it into consideration.

Comment: ah, do you want them matched across all documents? do you need to retain the document structure.

Comment: i need only events list with wanted elements.yes i want to check all elements in events list

Comment: My friend did you find anything?

Comment: I edited my answer to use `$filter` as the events are in an array.

Comment: thanx i will try now